# {{ items }} variable seems undefined in simple ansible code

Tags: ansible

I have very short and simple task in ansible, but no matter what, "item" variable is undefined.

```
- name: Prepare for install
  shell:
    cmd: "touch /root/testfile"
    delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
  - "host102"
  - "host103"
```

I'm always getting error

> *The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined. The error appears to be in '/runner/project/roles/<redacted>.yml*

I tried different combination of list, loops but no matter what, "item" is not filled with data.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Unrelated to problem but using `shell` to `touch` a file is a bad practice. Use the [`file` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html) with `state: touch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Your indentation of `delegate_to` is incorrect. You're now using it as an argument for the shell module, which isn't an argument.

This should work.

```yaml
- name: prepare for install
  shell: touch /root/testfile
  delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
  loop:
    - host102
    - host103
```